# how to get JSON array value from internet

Tags: arrays, json

I want to get value of an array from JSON code in internet. from this URL : http://olympics.clearlytech.com/api/v1/medals/

after that, I want to display that array of my script without rewrite that JSON code on this URL http://olympics.clearlytech.com/api/v1/medals/

so, what code (script) that I can use?

for example, I want to display value from this array

```
var JSONs = {
          example:['one','two','three']
};
```

the code is

```
document.write(JSONs.example[0]);
```

but if I want get the array value from the internet, what code/script that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, here is an example.  In the success event, turn the resulting json text into a json object.  You could also set the content type as `json` so you wouldn't have to call the `JSON.parse()`.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://olympics.clearlytech.com/api/v1/medals/",
        success: function(data) {
          var json = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

### This is another way of doing  the same i hope you asked how to parse through each value just try this in jsfiddle

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("here");
    $.getJSON("http://olympics.clearlytech.com/api/v1/medals/",function(data){
           $.each(data,function(key,value){
               alert(data[key].country_name);
               alert(data[key].rank); 

               console.log(data[key].rank));
           });
       });    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void handleResponse(String response) 

    {    
   //   display("Response:"+response);
        if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            JSONObject jso;
            try {
                jso = new JSONObject(response);


                    String status = jso.getString("status");
                    int valid=jso.getInt("valid");
              //     display("Welcome : "+UName);
                 if(valid>0)
                 {
                    if( status.equalsIgnoreCase("") || status==null ||  status.equalsIgnoreCase("Failed"))
                    {
                        invalid.setText("Invalid password");
                        //reset();
                        pwd.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //display(status);
                        intObj=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Design_Activity.class);
                        intObj.putExtra("Username", mUname);
                        startActivity(intObj);
                        MainActivity.this.finish();     
                    }

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     invalid.setText("Invalid userid");
                     uname.setText("");
                 }
                }
            catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, e1.getLocalizedMessage(), e1);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            display("Could not able to reach Server!");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Althought you want us to do everything, thats why your question went negative. Anyhow this is how you can do it in plain ajax

```
function getData(){
    // Initialize the Ajax request
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', 'http://olympics.clearlytech.com/api/v1/medals/');

    // Track the state changes of the request
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        // Ready state 4 means the request is done
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        // 200 is a successful return
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            alert(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
        }else{
            alert('Error: '+xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request
        }
        }
    }

    // Send the request to send-ajax-data.php
    xhr.send(null);
}
```